# How to hide the main menu and the toolbar of the 3D View?

Tags: interface, customization

I'd like to hide the main menu and the toolbar of the 3d View:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: From what I can gather, you're using an Apple computer. I work on Windows. The second row is the view's menu bar, THe first row is the global menu bar. For the view's menu bar, you can do it via context menu on the bar (right click on Windows), and select Show Header or Alt+F9. For the global menu, it used to be a part of the python console, but now it is stand-alone, so I'm not sure

Comment: There should be some kind of switch for Mac to integrate Blender menu into the app menu, it is present in some software, but it is a Mac only thing.

Comment: When you look for these kinds of things, the Preferences > Keymap (keyboard shortcuts) is very handy, because you can search all the commands. Also you have the space-bar (execute command). Interface switches may be spread acrross the Interface, System, Theme and Editing tabs of the Preferences window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**View** menu > **Area** > **Toggle Fullscreen Area**.

Keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Comment: ... and right-click on the header bar to disable *Show Header*